# Comparison between two string lists

Tags: c#

I have two string lists, I need to do a comparison and validate at least if one position is the same.
Can someone help me?

```
List<string> listA = new List<string>();
listA.Add("b");
listA.Add("c");
listA.Add("a");

List<string> listB = new List<string>();
listB.Add("h");
listB.Add("b");
listB.Add("d");
```

Expected output:

```
b = h false
b = b true (break)
b = d false
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? And what do you mean by one position is the same? That the value in both lists for at least one index is the same? Or that there is anywhere in listA a value that is in list B (and vis versa)

Comment: you mentioned "validate at least if one position is the same", does that mean the values in the list need to be equal *at the same index* in both lists, or simply if either list contains a value that is present in the other?

Comment: What if the two lists have no equal length?

Comment: Yes, that there is anywhere in listA a value that is in list B, and vis versa.

Comment: @Razor - please edit the question to include this last comment of yours. So it is clear what you are looking for

Comment: @Razor, given that you have accepted an answer, please change your question to match the answer. At the moment there is a mismatch between what you asked for and what you accepted as the answer...

Comment: If position matters maybe a list is not the best way to build up your data. Imo an array is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use LINQ:

```
if (listA.Intersect(listB).Any())
{
    //do smth;
}
```

Comment: An alternative: `listA.Any(listB.Contains)`

Answer (score 1):

Given that the lists are the same size, some function/method like:

```
for (int index = 0; index < listA.Count; index++) {
    if (listA[index] == listB[index]) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Should work.

If the lists arn't the same size, you can then do something like.

```
int smallListCount = listA.Count;
if (smallListCount > listB.Count) {
    smallListCount = listB.Count;
}
for (int index = 0; index < smallListCount; index++) { /*... codeblah*/ }
```

That'll make sure it'll only loop for as many elements as there are able to be compared in the smallest list.

---

Erp! If you don't care about the order of the indexes then...

You'll need some function/method that can take any input, then iterates over listB to see if there is a match, returning true... if well... it finds a match.
You'd then want to feed in the values of listA, and store the result for each element.

```
private bool CheckListForItem(List<string> listToCheck, string itemToCheckFor) {
    foreach(string item in listToCheck) {
        if (item == itemToCheckFor) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

which can then be used like:

```
bool[] results = new results[listA.Count];
for(int index = 0; index < listA.Count; index++) {
    results[index] = CheckListForItem(listB, listA[index]);
}
```

to obtain results for each individual item.

Note that this will have a complexity of O(n), I'd assume LINQ is faster. But hey, this exposes a potential implementation! Kinda.

Comment: I am not sure why this was marked as the accepted answer, given that it doesn't answer the OP's question. This will just compare list elements which are at the same position in both lists.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **Except** [LINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/getting-started-with-linq) extension method, which takes items only from the first list, that are not present in the second

```
List<string> resultList =  listA.Except(listB).ToList();
```

Comment: This is not what OP is looking for - "*that there is anywhere in listA a value that is in list B, and vis versa*"

Answer (score 0):

Here is something that does exactly what you want and doesnt use Linq if you arent familiar with it. 
We extend a List class and add CompareLists method to it and then called it to see if any value is the same in both lists.

```
    public static class Extensions
{      
    public static bool CompareLists(this List<string> listA, List<string> listB)
    {
        foreach (string s in listA)
        {
            foreach (string s1 in listB)
            {
                if (s.Equals(s1))
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

and then use it like

```
var result = listA.CompareLists(listB);
```

with a little tweaking you can make it return a list of objects that are or arent equal.

```
public static class Extensions
{      
    public static List<string> CompareLists(this List<string> listA, List<string> listB)
    {
        List<string> results = new List<string>();

        foreach (string s in listA)
        {
            foreach (string s1 in listB)
            {
                if (s.Equals(s1))
                {
                    results.Add(s);
                }
            }
        }
        return results;

    }
}
```